# Assistance with debugging in WinDbg

Tags: windbg

After running the Crash/Hang Analyzer in the DebugDiag tool it list that thread 17 is locking.

Running a !locks command in windbg also points to thread 17.

I am up to this point...

```
0:000> ~17 kb
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0261fcc4 7c827b69 77e6202c 00000002 0261fd14 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
0261fcc8 77e6202c 00000002 0261fd14 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
0261fd70 77e62fbe 00000002 7a3d0468 00000000 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x11a
0261fd8c 79f9a9d2 00000002 7a3d0468 00000000 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjects+0x18
0261fdac 79f9ab07 000f2ab0 0261feb0 000f32b0 mscorwks!SVR::WaitForFinalizerEvent+0x77
0261fdc0 79eac697 0261feb0 00000000 00000000 mscorwks!SVR::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadWorker+0x49
0261fdd4 79eac633 0261feb0 0261fe5c 79fb685f mscorwks!Thread::DoADCallBack+0x32a
0261fe68 79eac553 0261feb0 3aa1ce47 00000000 mscorwks!Thread::ShouldChangeAbortToUnload+0xe3
0261fea4 79f4431c 0261feb0 00000000 0010f080 mscorwks!Thread::ShouldChangeAbortToUnload+0x30a
0261fecc 79f4432d 79f9aabc 00000008 0261ff14 mscorwks!ManagedThreadBase_NoADTransition+0x32
0261fedc 79f45ecb 79f9aabc 3aa1cff7 00000000 mscorwks!ManagedThreadBase::FinalizerBase+0xd
0261ff14 79fd2733 00000000 00000003 ffffffff mscorwks!SVR::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadStart+0xbb
0261ffb8 77e6482f 000f32b0 00000000 00000000 mscorwks!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x49
0261ffec 00000000 79fd26ed 000f32b0 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x34
```

From my understanding that the stack in thread 17 was trying to run this last
`0261fcc4 7c827b69 77e6202c 00000002 0261fd14 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet`

What do I do from here to go further on my analysis?

Comment: This looks like the finalizer thread. If that is blocking, that is not a good idea. You can get additional info about managed code using the SOS.dll extension.

Comment: I have loaded sos.dll. Please shine some guidance on how do I exactly find out what file or DLL is causing the hang. When I also check the thread that is waiting, it also gives the same results as above..

Comment: The `!clrstack` command displays the managed call stack. If the finalizer is waiting for e.g. a lock, you can use the `!syncblk` command to investigate.

Comment: When I run !clrstack command on thread 17.
0:017> !clrstack
OS Thread Id: 0xe64 (17)
Failed to start stack walk: 80004005

Comment: On a thread that is waiting.
0:057> !clrstack
OS Thread Id: 0x1cac (57)
ESP       EIP     
261de3b0 7c82845c [ComPlusMethodFrameGeneric: 261de3b0] MCSBOCOMLib.MCSecurBOClass.Login3(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, Boolean, System.String, Boolean)

Comment: 0:000> !syncblk
Index SyncBlock MonitorHeld Recursion Owning Thread Info  SyncBlock Owner
-----------------------------
Total           338
CCW             2
RCW             49
ComClassFactory 0
Free            271

Comment: If anyone has any input please share, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I believe I misread the stack trace. Anyway, the finalizer thread seems to be waiting on events, which means that it is waiting for finalizer to run. This is perfectly normal. I.e. I don't believe this is where your problem is. Also, please update questions instead of adding comments to provide additional info.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the dump is not going to tell me much? Maybe its a database issue since it is waiting to write to the Sq l database?

Comment: Use the !uniqstack  to get an overview of native stack for all threads in your dump, sometimes it helps seeing the offending thread.